# Trying to use Linkage () function, but I keep getting an error message

Tags: linkage

I get this error when trying to carry out segmentation[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri2bU.jpg)

Comment: Please format the error in a code block instead of using an image.

Comment: I am new to this...let me figure how to

Comment: Please check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help